# Filter a CSV file by month with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to eliminate all rows from a huge CSV file, except for those logged in March. I have a PS script that works for other items, but doesn't seem to work for this:

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\Temp\Users_with_IP_20180409.CSV'
$startDate = "3/1/2018"
$endDate = "3/31/2018"

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | where { $_.LocalTime -ge $startDate -and $_.LocalTime -lt $endDate } | Set-Content $SourceFile
```

[image: Attaching an image of my CSV file.]

Comment: `Import-CSV $SourceFile | ?{(Get-Date $_.LocalTime).Month -ne 3} | Export-CSV $newSourceFile -NoType`

Comment: You seem to be viewing the contents of your CSV in Excel. IMHO this is bad practice because Excel will try to interpret the data and then change the way it is displayed - particularly when dealing with dates. Use Notepad++ or another text editor to see what is the true underlying data.

Comment: Your CSV file contains nothing but text; don't forget that ;)
Also consider using the `Import-Csv` CmdLet

Comment: EBGreen's solution works, though I needed to change the operator from -ne to -eq. Cheers for EBGreen.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the word eliminate. Sorry

Comment: I like your solution best, though. It runs more quickly than other solutions and is easy to reconfigure. I'd upvote if i could.

Answer (score 0):

A script with start-/end date casted to [datetime] :

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\Temp\Users_with_IP_20180409.CSV'
$TargetFile = 'C:\Temp\Users_with_IP_20180409_sans_March.CSV'
$startDate = [datetime]"3/1/2018"
$endDate   = ([datetime]"3/31/2018").AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)

(Import-Csv $SourceFile) | 
    Where-Object { (Get-Date $_.LocalTime) -lt $startDate -or
                   (Get-Date $_.LocalTime) -gt $endDate } | 
        Export-Csv $TargetFile -NoType
```

Comment: This will include anything that happens after 12:00am on 3/31/2018.

Comment: @EBGreen Changed, I doubt that's worth a downvote, whoever it was.

Comment: Oh it was me. A wrong answer is a wrong answer. Someone that used that code to collect billing information for instance would miss one day every month. Now that it is fixed I have removed the vote.